# Starting off with coordinate systems

Tags: 3d, coordinates

Where is a good place to start with learning how to program custom coordinate systems in a 3d environment?

Are there any good books on he topic of gaming coordinate systems? I would like to build a real life data structure based on techniques used for game programming.

Comment: What is wrong with the Cartesian Co-ordinate system or the Polar Co-ordinate system? What causes you to want a different one?

Comment: X Y and Z? I don't really know what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, "custom coordinate system" sounds strange. The most "custom" I've ever done was for a 2d game where the coordinates got mirrored and re-mirrored at one point with parallax scaling and stuff; it wasn't necessary, but I was in a hurry, and it ended up complicating things overmuch.. =)

Comment: I am confused on where the object is placed in the beginning? what coordinates will an object have? I am trying to create a coordinate system for a robot and using its movement, I want to calculate its current position.

Comment: You do not want to create a coordinate system. You want to use one, yes, but not create your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Books about Game Engine development usually have chapters/sections on coordinate systems:

[Game Coding Complete](http://amzn.com/1584506806) (Chapter 13)
[Game Engine Architecture](http://amzn.com/1568814135) (Chapter 4)
[3D Game Engine Design](http://amzn.com/0122290631) (Chapter 2)

Answer (score 1):

Also see http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/ . It's about the math used in coordinate systems for games. Has explanations for creating user coordinate systems and matrix transformations.

It should be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I can greatly recommend [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556229119). It covers 3D coordinate systems in great detail (and is not a pain to read).

Comment: Thanks. My issue is that I will be creating a coordinate system for a physical object which wouldnt need camera angle control etc. I will be mapping the objects movement using data from the accelerometer. How or where would the object start in this coordinate system, and how is it managed?